# How to capture fast signal response from Gate beam IR sensor

Tags: mosfet, relay, signal-integrity

I have purchased two IR RX/TX sensors. The datasheet is [here](https://www.centsys.co.za/PDF/PROD/i5/1059.D.01.0001%20i5%20user%20guide%20insert_15012019BM.pdf). I have also purchased an ESP32 microcontroller.

I want to use the beam in a way that every time someone walks across this beam (i.e. the beam breaks), it must send a signal to the ESP32 to trigger a siren.

My initial circuit is shown below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8gsKa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The input trigger from the IR relay output can last from 330ms to 2 seconds. Depends on how fast the beam is broken and then restored.

My questions:

1. How do I design this circuit to pick up the 300ms trigger? Should I be using something else besides the MOSFET in order to capture this fast step response produces from the IR beam relay?
2. Is this circuit appropriate in terms of signal integrity and also robustness?

Comment: Looks to me you just need code.

Comment: @jsotola that was a typo. It's not even 1ms. It's actually around 330ms. So really not that fast

Comment: @DKNguyen yup also thought about that. But just checking if there's any improvements from the hardware side

Comment: there is no 12 V connection at the sensor relay contacts ... there is only relay contact ... research `how to connect switch to ESP32`

Comment: @jsotola correct that 12V should not be there. But it is 12V relay coil. On the sensor IR beam side

Comment: you could connect the 12 V to the contacts and run a 2 wire cable to the ESP32 and put an opto-isolator or a small relay at the ESP32 ...  basically the same circuit as the diagram, but isolated